# How to properly set headers for a json request through curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I am new at API´s, Curl and Json. I need to link my appilcation with the an API.

The API I want to connect with has a CURL example which is this:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET  https://www.api.com -u 'user:token'
```

I have made some research and I make a request like this:

```
$url = "https://www.api.com";

    $headers = array(
        -H "Accept: application/json",
        -H "Content-type: application/json"
        -u 'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("user:token") // <---   
    );

        //initializing curl object
        $curl = curl_init();
        //adding fields to the curl object to enter the site
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');

        //executing the curl call and getting data back
        $json = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl); // close the connection
        //echo $json;   
        return $json;
```

I get the Json request but I still don´t understand the example the API gives. I even don´t know if I am setting well the Curl.

can someone explain to me how can I interpret the Curl example if I doing it well ?

Comment: Both codes should give you some response, evaluate that response. Is there any error?

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid PHP syntax:

```
$headers = array(
    -H "Accept: application/json",
    -H "Content-type: application/json"
    -u 'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("user:token") // <---   
);
```

---

You should use this instead:

```
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-type: application/json',
);
```

And for the auth, use this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
```